# Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'int'

Tags: python, int, jython, bukkit, operand

First of all, sorry for making two questions in short interval, but I solved last one so I need help again. I'm coding bukkit plugins with jython/python... I'm pretty new to python/jython and I don't understand where I'm making mistake, take look at the code:

```
(everything is under class hween(PythonPlugin))                      
def CandyChance(self):
    chance = self.cfg.getString("main.candydropchance") #this works, I tried to print it and result is 10 (which I entered in config before)
    chancetotal = chance / 100

@hook.event("block.BlockBreakEvent", "HIGHEST")        
def onBlockBreakEvent(event):
    #something
    chancetotal = pyplugin.CandyChance() 
    if("Random.nextDouble() <= %s"%chancetotal):
       #do something
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the full traceback? How did you print `chance`? Note that `print u"10"` and `print 10` produce the *exact same output*. Always use `repr()` (as in, `print repr(chance)`) to diagnose values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It prints 10" doesn't tell you anything about what type it is.  It's probably the string `"10"` and not the number `10` -- as you might guess from the method name `getString`.  You can't divide a string by a number.  Try doing:

```
chance = int(self.cfg.getString("main.candydropchance"))
```

Comment: It works, but it's not chance, it does that like it's 100% in config, not only 10 % ?

Comment: @AmarKalabić: If you are using Python 2.x, you should also change the calculation of `chancetotal` to something like `chancetotal = chance / 100.0` (note the decimal point).  Otherwise, the division will be *integer* division.

Comment: @AmarKalabić: Sorry, I can't understand your comment.  What do you mean "it's not chance"?  It does what like it's 100% in config?

Comment: @BrenBarn fixed it now, but can you take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582817/typeerror-nextdouble-self-arg-cant-be-coerced-to-java-util-random

Thanks!