# TypeError: nextDouble(): self arg can't be coerced to java.util.Random

Tags: java, python, jython, typeerror

I'm having problem with this Random java thing in jython. I'm coding bukkit plugins in python. Here's the code:

```
class hween(PythonPlugin):
   def CandyChance(self):
       chance = self.cfg.getDouble("main.candydropchance", 50) / 100 #in config, it's 10, so I must do this to get it like 0.1...
       return chance

   @hook.event("block.BlockBreakEvent", "HIGHEST")        
   def onBlockBreakEvent(event):
       chance = pyplugin.CandyChance()
       print chance #When I print chance out, it's 0.1 (10 is in config) which is good I believe
       if(Random.nextDouble("%s"%chance)):
          #do something
```

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: @gamesbariniac this is jython, not java.

This is jython version:

jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar

but if you need java version, its:

v7, build 1.7.0_17-b02

Comment: update to the latest version 2.8

Comment: @GamesBrainiac nothing changes, and as I see on maven.org site, 2.7 is latest version of jython standalone.jar...

Comment: You're right, I was seeing pydev. My bad,

Comment: @GamesBrainiac any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Okay then update to latest version 2.7.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Did it already, as I said, nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interactive Jython session that reproduces your error:

```
Jython 2.7b1 (default:ac42d59644e9, Feb 9 2013, 15:24:52)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_25
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from java.util import Random
>>> Random.nextDouble("0.1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: nextDouble(): self arg can't be coerced to java.util.Random
>>> Random.nextDouble()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: nextDouble(): expected 1 args; got 0
>>> Random().nextDouble()
0.3442604857098639
>>>
```

The [`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) method is not static and it does not take any arguments. You'll have to rethink how you use "this Random java thing" (it is not clear what you are trying to do).

Comment: I'm trying to make like chance, which is configurable. For example, if it's stated 50 in confing, it means that there is 50% that everything below that line will happen, or else:...

Comment: Fixed! Using pythons random.randint(1, 100) instead of jythons Random.